# render a twig template from inside a twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, rendering

I'm trying to render a twig template inside of another twig template but it doesn't work. i received this error:

Any help would be appreciated!

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Case
>   mismatch between loaded and declared class names:
>   FLY\BookingsBundle\Controller\postController vs
>   FLY\BookingsBundle\Controller\PostController") in
>   SonataUserBundle:Profile:show.html.twig at line 94.

show.html.twig

```
{% extends "SonataUserBundle:Profile:action.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}

    {% block content %}

    {{ render(controller('FLYBookingsBundle:post:new')) }}

    {% endblock content %}

{% endblock %}
```

this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace FLY\BookingsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Post;
use FLY\BookingsBundle\Form\PostType;

/**
 * Post controller.
 *
 * @Route("/post")
 */
class PostController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Post entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="post")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $findEntities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->findAll();
        $entities  = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate($findEntities,$this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1),9
        );
        return array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="post_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("FLYBookingsBundle:Post:new.html.twig")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Post();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a Post entity.
     *
     * @param Post $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(Post $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('post_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));



        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="post_new")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Post();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="post_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="post_edit")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Creates a form to edit a Post entity.
    *
    * @param Post $entity The entity
    *
    * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
    */
    private function createEditForm(Post $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('post_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }
    /**
     * Edits an existing Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="post_update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Template("FLYBookingsBundle:Post:edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
    /**
     * Deletes a Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="post_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Post entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('post_delete', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change case of `post` in your twig template, change:

```
{{ render(controller('FLYBookingsBundle:post:new')) }}
```

to

```
{{ render(controller('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:new')) }}
```

and you should be good

Comment: Thanks a lot it work. :) but now my form is not rendering nicely even the scrollbar disappear, i will try fix it .